# Deleting Duplicates while ignoring blank cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have some code in VBA that is attempting to delete duplicate transaction IDs. However, i'd like to ammend the code to only delete duplicates that have a transaction ID - so, if there is no transaction ID, i'd like that row to be left alone. Here is my code below:

```
With MySheet
    newLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    newLastCol = .Cells(5 & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set Newrange = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(newLastRow, newLastCol))
    Newrange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=32, Header:= _
        xlYes
End With
```

I was also wondering - in the remove.duplicates command - is there a way where I can have the column I want looked at to be named rather than have it be 32 in case I add or remove columns at a later date?
Here is an image of the data: I'd like the ExchTransID column that have those 3 blank spaces to be left alone. 
[image]

Comment: sounds like you need to do a loop to assess what criteria are met... *If len(cells(i,11).value) > 0 Then* may be a good start for you.

Comment: Are you able to turn this table into an official Excel "table"? Insert -> Table. If you can, then you've turned the table into what Excel calls a ListObject in VBA. One of the nice things about ListObjects is that you can refer to columns by their name in VBA code.

Comment: No I can't really have as a table - I suppose the column issue isn't the most pressing

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. They simplify these types of tasks. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Modify and try the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, Times As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String

    'Indicate the sheet your want to work with
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row with IDs
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Set the range with all IDS
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & Lastrow)
        'Loop column from buttom to top
        For i = Lastrow To 1 Step -1
            str = .Range("A" & i).Value
            If str <> "" Then
                Times = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, str)
                If Times > 1 Then
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```